# Sign Up Form won't scroll

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm downloading Signup form for my site [codepen.io/GeBuOr/full/mJJmgx/](http://codepen.io/GeBuOr/full/mJJmgx/)  But It won't scroll if I add more fields in the signup section. Please guide me. Thanks.

[image]

```js
var LoginModalController = {
    tabsElementName: ".logmod__tabs li",
    tabElementName: ".logmod__tab",
    inputElementsName: ".logmod__form .input",
    hidePasswordName: ".hide-password",
    
    inputElements: null,
    tabsElement: null,
    tabElement: null,
    hidePassword: null,
    
    activeTab: null,
    tabSelection: 0, // 0 - first, 1 - second
    
    findElements: function () {
        var base = this;
        
        base.tabsElement = $(base.tabsElementName);
        base.tabElement = $(base.tabElementName);
        base.inputElements = $(base.inputElementsName);
        base.hidePassword = $(base.hidePasswordName);
        
        return base;
    },
    
    setState: function (state) {
     var base = this,
            elem = null;
        
        if (!state) {
            state = 0;
        }
        
        if (base.tabsElement) {
         elem = $(base.tabsElement[state]);
            elem.addClass("current");
            $("." + elem.attr("data-tabtar")).addClass("show");
        }
  
        return base;
    },
    
    getActiveTab: function () {
        var base = this;
        
        base.tabsElement.each(function (i, el) {
           if ($(el).hasClass("current")) {
               base.activeTab = $(el);
           }
        });
        
        return base;
    },
   
    addClickEvents: function () {
     var base = this;
        
        base.hidePassword.on("click", function (e) {
            var $this = $(this),
                $pwInput = $this.prev("input");
            
            if ($pwInput.attr("type") == "password") {
                $pwInput.attr("type", "text");
                $this.text("Hide");
            } else {
                $pwInput.attr("type", "password");
                $this.text("Show");
            }
        });
 
        base.tabsElement.on("click", function (e) {
            var targetTab = $(this).attr("data-tabtar");
            
            e.preventDefault();
            base.activeTab.removeClass("current");
            base.activeTab = $(this);
            base.activeTab.addClass("current");
            
            base.tabElement.each(function (i, el) {
                el = $(el);
                el.removeClass("show");
                if (el.hasClass(targetTab)) {
                    el.addClass("show");
                }
            });
        });
        
        base.inputElements.find("label").on("click", function (e) {
           var $this = $(this),
               $input = $this.next("input");
            
            $input.focus();
        });
        
        return base;
    },
    
    initialize: function () {
        var base = this;
        
        base.findElements().setState().getActiveTab().addClickEvents();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    LoginModalController.initialize();
});
```

```css
@import "bourbon";

html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

$red: #f44336;
$pink: #E91E63;
$purple: #9C27B0;
$deep-purple: #673AB7;
$indigo: #3F51B5;
$blue: #2196F3;
$light-blue: #03A9F4;
$cyan: #00BCD4;
$teal: #009688;
$green: #4CAF50;
$light-green: #8BC34A;
$lime: #CDDC39;
$yellow: #FFEB3B;
$amber: #FFC107;
$orange: #FF9800;
$deep-orange: #FF5722;
$brown: #795548;
$grey: #9E9E9E;
$blue-grey: #607D8B;

$array-color-swatch: (
 "red":         $red,
 "pink":        $pink,
 "purple":        $purple,
 "deep-purple":   $deep-purple,
 "indigo":        $indigo,
 "blue":          $blue,
 "light-blue":    $light-blue,
 "cyan":          $cyan,
 "teal":          $teal,
 "green":         $green,
 "light-green":   $light-green,
 "lime":          $lime,
 "yellow":        $yellow,
 "amber":         $amber,
 "orange":        $orange,
 "deep-orange":   $deep-orange,
 "brown":         $brown,
 "grey":          $grey,
 "blue-grey":     $blue-grey
);

// logmod
$logmod-baseline: 24px;
$logmod-bg: rgba(#000, 0.2);
$logmod-zindex: 1;

.logmod {
    display: block;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    background: $logmod-bg;
    z-index: $logmod-zindex;
    @include clearfix();
    
    // .logmod__wrapper
    &__wrapper {
        display: block;
        background: #FFF;
        position: relative;
        max-width: 550px;
        border-radius: 4px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 18px rgba(#000, 0.2);
        margin: ($logmod-baseline * 5) auto;
    }
    
    // .logmod__close
    &__close {
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        right: 50%;
        background: url("http://imgh.us/close_white.svg") no-repeat scroll 0% 0% transparent;
        text-indent: 100%;
        white-space: nowrap;
        overflow: hidden;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: -(($logmod-baseline * 2) + $logmod-baseline);
        margin-right: -($logmod-baseline);
        width: $logmod-baseline * 2;
        height: $logmod-baseline * 2;
    }
    
    // .logmod__container
    &__container {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        @include clearfix;
    }
    
    // .logmod__tab
    &__tab {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        height: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        visibility: hidden;
        
        &-wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        
        &.show {
            opacity: 1;
            height: 100%;
            visibility: visible;
        }
    }
    
    // .logmod__tabs
    &__tabs {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        @include clearfix;
        
        li {
            &.current {
                a {
                    background: #FFF;
                    color: #333;
                }
            }
            
            a {
                width: 50%;
                position: relative;
                float: left;
                text-align: center;
                background: #D2D8D8;
                line-height: $logmod-baseline * 3;
                height: $logmod-baseline * 3;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: #809191;
                text-transform: uppercase;
                font-weight: 700;
                font-size: 16px;
                cursor: pointer;
                
                &:focus {
                    outline: dotted 1px;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // .logmod__heading
    &__heading {
        text-align: center;
        padding: ($logmod-baseline / 2) 0 ($logmod-baseline / 2) 0;
        
        // .logmod__heading-subtitle
        &-subtitle {
            display: block;
            font-weight: 400;
            font-size: 15px;
            color: #888;
            line-height: $logmod-baseline * 2;
        }
    }
    
    // .logmod__form
    &__form {
        border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    }
    
    // .logmod__alter
    &__alter {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        margin-top: 7px;
        @include clearfix;
        
        .connect:last-child {
            border-radius: 0 0 4px 4px;
        }
    }
}

// [classname] [background-color] [color]
$items: facebook #3b5998 #FFF, googleplus #dd4b39 #FFF; 
.connect {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: $logmod-baseline * 3;
    line-height: $logmod-baseline * 3;
    text-decoration: none;
    @include clearfix;
    
    &:focus,
    &:hover,
    &:visited {
        color: #FFF;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    // .connect__icon
    &__icon {
        vertical-align: middle;
        float: left;
        width: 70px;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 22px;
    }
    
    // .connect__context
    &__context {
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: center;
    }
    
    @each $item in $items {
        &.#{nth($item, 1)} {
            background: nth($item, 2);
            color: nth($item, 3);
            
            a {
                color: nth($item, 3);
            }
            
            .connect__icon {
                background: darken(nth($item, 2), 13%);
            }
        }
    }
}

.simform {
    position: relative;
    
    // .simform__actions
    &__actions {
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 14px;
        @include clearfix;
        
        .sumbit {
            height: $logmod-baseline * 2;
            float: right;
            color: #FFF;
            width: 50%;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 16px;
            background: $green;
            @include clearfix;
            @extend .btn;
            margin-top: 7px;
        }
        
        // .simform__actions-sidetext
        &-sidetext {
            display: inline-block;
            float: left;
            width: 50%;
            padding: 0 10px;
            margin: 9px 0 0 0;
            color: #8C979E;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: $logmod-baseline;
            @include clearfix;
        }
    }
}

.sminputs {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E5E5E5;
    @include clearfix;
    
    .input {
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        width: 50%;
        height: ($logmod-baseline * 3) - 1;
        padding: 11px $logmod-baseline;
        //padding: ($logmod-baseline / 2) 15px 0 ($logmod-baseline / 1.5);
        border-right: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
        border-bottom: none;
        float: left;
        background-color: #FFF;
        border-radius: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: none;
        appearance: none;
        
        &.active {
            background: #eee;
            
            .hide-password {
                background: #eee;
            }
        }
        
        &.full {
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        label {
            overflow: hidden;
            text-overflow: ellipsis;
            white-space: nowrap;
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            letter-spacing: 1px;
            font-weight: 700;
            font-size: 12px;
            cursor: pointer;
            line-height: $logmod-baseline;
        }
        
        input {
            postion: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            height: $logmod-baseline;
            font-size: 15px;
            line-height: $logmod-baseline * 0.8;
            color: #555;
            border-radius: 4px;
            vertical-align: middle;
            box-shadow: none;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            width: 100%;
            height: auto;
            border: none;
            padding: 0;
            cursor: pointer;
            background-color: transparent;
            color: rgba(75, 89, 102, 0.85);
        }
    }
    
    .hide-password {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
        padding: 0 15px;
  border-left: 1px solid #e4e4e4;
  font-size: 14px;
        background: #FFF;
        overflow: hidden;
  color: #444;
        cursor: pointer;
        margin-top: $logmod-baseline / 2;
        line-height: ($logmod-baseline * 2);
  }
}

html {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 24px;
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.btn {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: normal;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
    outline-offset: 0;  
    font-weight: 400;
    box-shadow: none;
    min-width: 90px;
    padding: 10px 14px;

    &.full {
        width: 100%;
    }

    &.lg {
        min-width: 125px;
        padding: 17px 14px;
        font-size: 22px;
        line-height: 1.3;
    }

    &.sm {
        min-width: 65px;
        padding: 4px 12px;
        font-size: 14px;
    }

    &.xs {
        min-width: 45px;
        padding: 2px 10px;
        font-size: 10px;
        line-height: 1.5;
    }
    
    &.circle {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 56px;
        height: 56px;
        min-width: 56px;
        line-height: 1;
        padding: 0;
        border-radius: 50%;

        &.lg {
            width: 78px;
            height: 78px;
            min-width: 78px;
        }

        &.sm {
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            min-width: 40px;
        }

        &.xs {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px; 
            min-width: 30px;
        }
    }
    
    &:focus, 
    &:active, 
    &.active, 
    &:active:focus, 
    &.active:focus {
        outline: 0;
        outline-offset: 0;  
        box-shadow: none;
    }
    
    @each $color-name, $color in $array-color-swatch {
        &.#{$color-name} {
            background: $color;
            color: #FFF;
            
            &:active,
        &:focus {
         background-color: darken($color, 9%);
        }

        &:hover {
         background-color: darken($color, 5%);
        }
        }
    }
}

.special {
    color: $red;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
    
    &:before {
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        height: 1px;
        bottom: 0px;
        left: 0;
        background: #f00;
        visibility: hidden;
        transform: scaleX(0);
        transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out 0s;
    }
    
    &:hover {
        transition: all 0.15s ease-out;
        
        &:before {
            visibility: visible;
            transform: scaleX(1);
        }
    }
}

#baseline {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-image: url(http://basehold.it/i/24);
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="logmod">
  <div class="logmod__wrapper">
    <span class="logmod__close">Close</span>
    <div class="logmod__container">
      <ul class="logmod__tabs">
        <li data-tabtar="lgm-2"><a href="#">Login</a></li>
        <li data-tabtar="lgm-1"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div class="logmod__tab-wrapper">
      <div class="logmod__tab lgm-1">
        <div class="logmod__heading">
          <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your personal details <strong>to create an acount</strong></span>
        </div>
        <div class="logmod__form">
          <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
            <div class="sminputs">
              <div class="input full">
                <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="email" size="50" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sminputs">
              <div class="input string optional">
                <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="text" size="50" />
              </div>
              <div class="input string optional">
                <label class="string optional" for="user-pw-repeat">Repeat password *</label>
                <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw-repeat" placeholder="Repeat password" type="text" size="50" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="simform__actions">
              <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value="Create Account" />
              <span class="simform__actions-sidetext">By creating an account you agree to our <a class="special" href="#" target="_blank" role="link">Terms & Privacy</a></span>
            </div> 
          </form>
        </div> 
        <div class="logmod__alter">
          <div class="logmod__alter-container">
            <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
              <div class="connect__icon">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="connect__context">
                <span>Create an account with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
              </div>
            </a>
              
            <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
              <div class="connect__icon">
                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="connect__context">
                <span>Create an account with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="logmod__tab lgm-2">
        <div class="logmod__heading">
          <span class="logmod__heading-subtitle">Enter your email and password <strong>to sign in</strong></span>
        </div> 
        <div class="logmod__form">
          <form accept-charset="utf-8" action="#" class="simform">
            <div class="sminputs">
              <div class="input full">
                <label class="string optional" for="user-name">Email*</label>
                <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-email" placeholder="Email" type="email" size="50" />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="sminputs">
              <div class="input full">
                <label class="string optional" for="user-pw">Password *</label>
                <input class="string optional" maxlength="255" id="user-pw" placeholder="Password" type="password" size="50" />
                      <span class="hide-password">Show</span>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="simform__actions">
              <input class="sumbit" name="commit" type="sumbit" value="Log In" />
              <span class="simform__actions-sidetext"><a class="special" role="link" href="#">Forgot your password?<br>Click here</a></span>
            </div> 
          </form>
        </div> 
        <div class="logmod__alter">
          <div class="logmod__alter-container">
            <a href="#" class="connect facebook">
              <div class="connect__icon">
                <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="connect__context">
                <span>Sign in with <strong>Facebook</strong></span>
              </div>
            </a>
            <a href="#" class="connect googleplus">
              <div class="connect__icon">
                <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i>
              </div>
              <div class="connect__context">
                <span>Sign in with <strong>Google+</strong></span>
              </div>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Added code, and screenshot

Answer (score 0):

add the following property to your .logmod CSS rule

```
overflow: scroll;
```

That should work for you

Example: http://codepen.io/Skibbereen-Coderdojo/pen/apQXxW

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
//from codepen
.logmod{ // main container
  display: block;
  position: fixed; //ISSUE pos fixed change to ABSOLUTE
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  opacity: 1;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}
```